# How to call TerminateProcess with Administrative Privilage?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How to call `TerminateProcess` with Administrative Privileges?

When I try to call `TerminateProcess` on a COM executable (Sample.exe) it is returning "ACCESS DENIED" Error.

I tried the TASKKILL command as well, it is also returning the same error.

But when I execute the "TASKKILL /F /IM Sample.exe" in Command Prompt (Opened -Run As Admin). It killed Sample.exe successfully

Note: I created the handle of sample.exe using the `OpenProcess` function.

Can someone suggest a good solution?

Comment: Your application needs to be running with the appropriate permissions. Try running your app as admin.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi- Yes, It was running as Admin only

Comment: You need to give your process the SeDebugPrivilege, even when running as an Administrator.  Here is a link to Microsoft's code for calling TerminateProcess with a handle from OpenProcess https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/131065

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx). The handle must have the PROCESS_TERMINATE access right.

Answer (score -1):

Your application needs to be ran with such permissions. To say shortly, with admin rights. You can restart your program by using ShellExecuteEx and runas as admin.

Comment: This is not true, Christopher Oicles comment is right.

Comment: Your comment is not a true. You need SeDebugPrivilege only for terminating processes with IL > HIGH

Comment: What is it "IL" and what is "HIGH" ?