# How can i run ShellExecute with Administrator privilege in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to kill one application named, Sample.exe

I tried with TerminateProcess, it was returning ACCESS_DENIED error while killing the Sample.exe. Later I identified it is an Access Rights issue.

How can I use ShellExecute API for killing the Sample.exe with Administrador privilege

::ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, L"taskkill", L"/F /T /IM Sample.exe", NULL, SW_HIDE);

Can anyone suggest a good solution?

Thanks,
Sreekumar Sasidharan

Comment: You can use the `"runas"` verb to launch the process elevated if that helps.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Where should I pass this "runas"?

Comment: As the verb parameter in `ShellExecute`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter- there is no parameter under ShellExecute. Do i need to user SHELLEXECUTEINFO ?

Comment: `lpOperation` *A pointer to a null-terminated string, referred to in this case as a **verb***. But `ShellExecuteEx` is preferred these days, `ShellExecute` exists only for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the problem, instead of applying the solution, as outlined in comments to your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35316427/1889329)? Your process must be opened with the `PROCESS_TERMINATE` access right, to call [TerminateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714.aspx) on it.

Answer (score 0):

If...

```
taskkill /F /T /IM Sample.exe
```

...won't work at the (regular, non-elevated) command line prompt, then...

```
::ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, L"taskkill", L"/F /T /IM Sample.exe", NULL, SW_HIDE);
```

...in your code will equally fail when run as the regular non-elevated user.

Solution is to run your program *as-admin* (elevated). You must of course realize how huge a security hole this would be if it worked otherwise.

Comment: or use the `runas` verb

Answer (score 0):

The runas verb can be used to elevate permissions.
ShellExecute as Admin:

```
  oShell:= createOleObject(‘Shell.Application’);
  oShell.ShellExecute(‘maXbox4.exe’,’firstdemo.txt’, ”, ‘runas’, 1)
  oShell:= unassigned;
```